# Javascript event listener to start video at certain time and stop video after certain duration

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I'm trying to get my video (locally hosted, not streamed) to start after a certain time and stop after a certain duration.  Someone here helped me out here with Javascript, but it's not working for me -- no effect on time of playback at all.

So, in my header, I've called the javascript like this:

```
<script src="Backend/build/Timer.js"></script>
```

And the actual javascript looks like this:

```
// JavaScript Document

var starttime = 2000;  // start at 2 seconds
var endtime = 4000;    // stop at 4 seconds

var video = document.getElementById('player1');
video.currentTime = starttime;

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (video.currentTime >= endtime) {
        video.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Wrap your code into a function and invoke that function in document ready or body load event handler, otherwise `video` variable value may be invalid.
2. According to [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-currenttime):

   > The `currentTime` attribute must, on getting, return the current playback position, expressed in **seconds**. On setting, if the media element has a current media controller, then it must throw an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception; otherwise, the user agent must seek to the new value (which might raise an exception).

   If you want to start playing the video at 2 seconds and stop at 4 seconds (in the video time stamp), set `starttime`, `endtime` to 2, 4 respectively, not 2000, 4000. Furthermore, before seeking to `starttime`, you must load the video resource once

   ```
   function playVideo() {
       var starttime = 2;  // start at 2 seconds
       var endtime = 4;    // stop at 4 seconds

       var video = document.getElementById('player1');

       //handler should be bound first
       video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
          if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
               this.pause();
           }
       }, false);

       //suppose that video src has been already set properly
       video.load();
       video.play();    //must call this otherwise can't seek on some browsers, e.g. Firefox 4
       try {
           video.currentTime = starttime;
       } catch (ex) {
           //handle exceptions here
       }
   }
   ```