# How to play a video from the nth second?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Let’s say I have a 4 minute video and I want it to start playing from the 25th second and not from the beginning.

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
  <source src="back.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: @Xufox yup i was thinking the same xD , could you guide me through the javascript method?

Answer (score 8):

Try appending `#t=TIME`

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
  <source src="back.mp4#t=25" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

W3.org: Media Fragments URI - http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/

Comment: wow , this is the easiest method so far , thanks a lot !

Comment: Everyone needs to know about this!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 25;
}, false);
```

Comment: Yep, that’s the basic approach. A little bit more explanation would be appreciated, though.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try it out !

Answer (score 1):

Yes Mohit, I've been looking for a very same functionality earlier on, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140539/javascript-event-listener-to-start-video-at-certain-time-and-stop-video-after-ce), you can try this snippet of javascript code, it worked for me; [it is also a method to stop the video at a certain time]

```
function playVideo() {
    var starttime = 2;  // start at 2 seconds
    var endtime = 4;    // stop at 4 seconds

    var video = document.getElementById('player1');

    //handler should be bound first
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
       if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
            this.pause();
        }
    }, false);

    //suppose that video src has been already set properly
    video.load();
    video.play();    //must call this otherwise can't seek on some browsers, e.g. Firefox 4
    try {
        video.currentTime = starttime;
    } catch (ex) {
        //handle exceptions here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try it out !